# Show $u_{xx}$ satisfies the PDE $u_t+cu_x=0$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, linear-pde

> Let $c$ be a constant and consider the following Cauchy problem associated with the inhomogeneous transport PDE $$u_t+cu_x=x, \ u(x,0)=x+2.$$
>   a) Show $u_{xx}$ satisfies the homogeneous PDE and homogeneous initial data associated with the above Cauchy problem, i.e. $u_t+cu_x=0$ and $u(x,0)=0$.
>
> b) Hence explain why $u_{xx}\equiv 0$
>
> c) Hence, or otherwise, solve the original inhomogeneous Cauchy problem.

Honestly I don't really understand what the question is asking for. How can $u_{xx}$ satisfy a homogeneous, first-order PDE?

If we take 
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(u_t+cu_x\right)&=0 \\
u_{tx}+cu_{xx}&=0
\end{align}

Comment: It would mean $u_{txx}+cu_{xxx}=0$, but maybe an assumption is missing

Comment: Can you state the exact question as stated in the book (or whatever the source of the question is)?

Comment: I've just made an edit. I've also included parts $(b)$ and $(c)$, just in case this indicates what to do in part $(a)$. Thanks everyone!

Comment: That helps a lot. "How can $u_{xx}$ satisfy a homogeneous, first-order PDE?" Let $v = u_{xx}$ and check to see if $v_t + c v_x = 0$ and $v(x,0) = 0$. If so, then $v$ is a solution to the given homogeneous PDE.

Comment: @littleO Thanks!! I'll give it a go.

Comment: @littleO I have shown that $v(x,t)=0$. Is sufficient for result $a)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation in OP is somewhat confusing.

a) Let us follow the problem resolution as suggested by @littleO in the comments. Thus, we differentiate twice the PDE problem $u_t + c u_x = x$, $u(x,0) = x+2$ with respect to $x$:
$$
u_{txx} + c u_{xxx} = 0,
\qquad
u_{xx}(x,0) = 0 .
$$
Swapping derivatives yields $v_t + cv_x = 0$, $v(x,0) = 0$, where $v=u_{xx}$. Up to the notation for $u_{xx}$, this is exactly what is asked in a).

b) The solution of the Cauchy problem satisfied by $v$ can be deduced from the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics), and we have $v=u_{xx}\equiv 0$.

c) The method of characteristics is applied to $u_t + c u_x = x$, $u(x,0) = x+2$, which leads to
$$ u(x,t) = (x-ct) + 2 + (x-ct)t + \tfrac{1}{2} c t^2 . $$
Note that $u_{xx} \equiv 0$, as predicted in b).

---

Alternative approaches for c):

- Set $w = u - \frac12 x^2/c$, which gives $w_t=u_t$ and $w_x=u_x - x/c$. Hence $w_t + cw_x =0$ with $w(x,0) = x+2 - \frac12 x^2/c$, which can be solved by applying the method of characteristics.
- Set $w = u - (x+2)$, which gives $w_t=u_t$ and $w_x=u_x - 1$. Hence $w_t + cw_x = c+x$ with $w(x,0) = 0$, which can be solved by applying the method of characteristics.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused as to how the steady state solution was found. I think my problem is similar to this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3130512/boundary-value-problem-u-t-u-xx-coshx-0x4-t0-pde?rq=1 I'll keep working at it, this will be marked as the accepted solution as I agree with you working :) you're a legend

Comment: @Bell a steady-state solution is a function of $x$ (steady = no time-evolution), which satisfies both the PDE and the boundary conditions. There is such a function in the parabolic BVP case, but not in the present hyperbolic IVP case!

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

From $u_t + c u_x = 0$

$$
\partial_x(u_t + c u_x) = u_{tx}+c u_{xx} = 0 \Rightarrow u_{xx} = -\frac 1c u_{tx}
$$

and now

$$
(u_{xx})_t + c(u_{xx})_x = \left(-\frac 1c u_{tx}\right)_t + c\left(-\frac 1c u_{tx}\right)_x = -\frac 1c\partial_t\partial_x\left(u_t+cu_x\right) = 0
$$

Also making $U(x,t) = u(x,t)+\frac{x^2}{2c}$ we have

$$
U_t+c U_x = 0\Rightarrow U(x,t) = \phi(x-c t)\Rightarrow u(x,t) = \phi(x-ct)-\frac{x^2}{2c}
$$

but $u(x,0) = x+2$ hence

$$
x+2 = \phi(x) - \frac{x^2}{2c}
$$

and finally

$$
u(x,t) = \frac{(x-c t)^2}{2c}+(x-c t)+2 -\frac{x^2}{2c}
$$